# Custombox (js plugin) not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to be able to setup custombox properly and am doing something wrong.
Code:

```
<link href="css/custombox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
<div class="button">Click</div>
<div style="display:none;" class="open">WORD</div>
<script>
$(function() {
$('.button').on('click', function( e ) {
    Custombox.open({
        target: '.open',
        effect: 'fadein'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custombox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the issue or the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custombox does not provide a static `open` method. You need to initialize an instance first, then `open()`:

```
$('.button').on('click', function( e ) {
   var modal = new Custombox.modal({
      content: {
        effect: 'fadein',
        target: '.open'
      }
   });

   modal.open();
});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxfb3mon/1/)